# How to perform an action when a file is not present with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I want to make a list of servers that don't have a particular file.

I made the following Ansible playbook:

```yaml
 - name: "If file not in /apps"
   hosts: all
   tasks:

    - name: Find apps
      find:
        paths: /apps/
        patterns: "*"
        file_type: directory
      register: apps

    - name: Show file paths
      with_items: "{{ apps.files }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
```

This returns a message with the app directories. I would like to check if a certain file is present in a subfolder, and if the file is ***not*** present, I want to run a script.

A pseudocode example of what I want:

```
for folder in "/apps/*":    
    if file not in folder:
        print(item.path)
```

How do I do that? I just can't find anything and I've been trying for several hours now.

[image: The target server]

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your question

> *I would like to check if a certain file is present in a subfolder, and if the file is not present*

you may use the following approach.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    SEARCH_PATH: "/home/user"
    SEARCH_FILE: "test.txt"

  tasks:

  - name: Check if file exists
    stat:
      path: "{{ SEARCH_PATH }}/{{ SEARCH_FILE }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "The file does not exist!"
    when: not result.stat.exists

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "The file does exist!"
    when: result.stat.exists
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] ************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: The file does not exist!
```

or

```
TASK [Show result] ********
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: The file does exist!
```

depending on when the file under `/home/user` or the path exists at all.

**Thanks to further Q&A**

- [How to check if a file exists in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654286/)
- [Ansible: Include task only if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119521/)
- [How can I run a Ansible task only if a file or directory does NOT exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021384/)
- [Ansible: Test to check file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433907/)

**Documentation**

- [`stat` module – Retrieve file or file system status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html)
- [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the file has version numbering at the end, and not necessarily the same version number. `stat` cannot deal with that, right? I would also like a list of apps without the file but that is trivial to add I'd say. Although I don't quite understand how to select just the path from the result of the `find` method.

Comment: `stat` will need the directory or filename. To get just the path from a `find` result without the filename you can use the filter `result.path | basename `.